# Error - null: InvocationTargetException - org.springframework.boot.logging.DeferredLog

Tags: spring-boot

Spring Boot application with the `spring-boot-devtools` dependency does not start because of the following error:

```
An exception occured while running. 
null: InvocationTargetException: 
org/springframework/boot/logging/DeferredLog: 
org.springframework.boot.logging.DeferredLog
```

I saw that in the package `org.springframework.boot: spring-boot-devtools:1.3.0.M5`there is no class `DeferredLog`, but on the following Github's repository

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot

it is present.

What is wrong? How to fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best guess is that you are trying to use devtools with Spring Boot 1.2. You obviously can't do that.

If you want to use `M5` upgrade your project to use Spring Boot `1.3.0.M5`. You can do that by upgrading the version in the parent or change the version of the `spring-boot-dependencies` (if you're using Maven).

More info about dependency management [in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent)

Answer (score 0):

spring-boot-devtools:1.3.0.M5 required spring-boot 1.3.0
just change  at pom.xml and mvn clean package

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: `spring-boot-devtools` `1.3.0.M5` does not require the snapshot to run. This is a milestone release so you should be able to just use tat.

Comment: I meant that the required version of the spring-boot 1.3.0 as only there appeared a class DeferredLog

Comment: your example should use `1.3.0.M5` then, not snapshot.